# Right derived derivations

Tags: homological-algebra, derived-functors

Let $k$ be a field and $A$ a graded algebra (If it simplifies things, we can assume that $A$ is graded commutative, too). The Lie algebra of derivations
is the linear subspace $Der(A)\subset End_k(A)$ of the vector space of $k$-endomorpisms of $A$, which is a solution set to the equation

$D(a\cdot b)= D(a)\cdot b +(-1)^{|a|} a \cdot D(b)$ for $a,b\in A$ and $D\in End_k(A)$.

The Lie bracket is given by the commutator $[D,D']:= D \circ D' - D' \circ D$

---

What is the **right derived (dfg) Lie algebra of derivations**, often written as $\mathbb{D}er(A)$, in this context?

Is it the dfg Lie algebra of **graded** derivations? I.e. $|D|\neq 0$ and we have

$D(a\cdot b)= D(a)\cdot b +(-1)^{|D|+|a|} a \cdot D(b)$

Comment: You put the tags (homological-algebra) and (derived-functors) on this question; do you know what [Derived functors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derived_functor) are? (Nitpick: "differential graded" is almost always abbreviated as "dg-", not "dfg-"... Does the "f" mean anything special in your case?)

Comment: Not sure how to interpret your comment. The 'f' was a carelessness. Not in sync with the mainstream typo so to say.  But for the first part of the comment: You say that right derived derivations are not obtained by some kind of derived functor calculus? (Because your nebulous comment seems to imply that).

Comment: No, right derived derivations *are* obtained by derived functor calculus. $\mathbb{D}er$ is simply the right derived functor of $Der$ (basically: take a projective resolution of $A$ and apply $Der$ to get $\mathbb{D}er$). It's me that doesn't understand why you would think that $Der$ is the set of "ungraded" derivations while $\mathbb{D}er$ is the set of "graded" derivations... Nothing suggests that. So I'm wondering if you know what the adjective "right derived" means.

Comment: Because I don't know what comes out, if you compute $\mathbb{D}er(A)$. I mean it is one thing to say its the right derived functor of $Der()$, but another to actually give the result, i.e. say what it is on the object $A$. Graded derivation was just a guess. Based on the fact that derived commutative rings are basically dgc rings.